# Why is EPS looked at much more than FCF/S (Free Cash Flow Per Share)

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets, stock-analysis

I understand that eps is an  important metric to look at when analyzing a company. (And I wont go into all the details of eps) But at the end of the day, the amount "you" have in "your" bank account, is FCF. So shouldn't  FCF be more looked at.
(AMZN is good example in its "beginning" years had low EPS and High FCF, due to its unique  business model)

Comment: If I promise to pay you $500 next week, should investors buy your shares today, or next week?

Comment: If shares are trading below $500 let’s say $490  then do it today. Assuming you are completely confident I can pay the $500.

Comment: @user253751 but I don’t think that’s what you are trying to get at. Pls explain

Comment: and when everyone keeps buying the shares as long as they are less than $500, the share price goes up until it is $500, yes?

Comment: @user253751  Yes (unless the company can generate revenue in the future,the stock price may go even higher),

Comment: therefore the (total) share price would go up $500 if we earned $500 today even though it won't be cash until next week?